# propagating Exception from inside of a forEach loop

Tags: java, exception, unhandled-exception, throws

```
public controllerMethod() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
  getVehicles(req);
}

public List<vehicles> getVehicles(A req) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
   someObject.forEach(obj -> {  
      getVehicles2(req); //try catch resolves but why wouldn't throws handle this ? 
   }
}

public getVehicles2(A req) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{

}
```

I am trying to call getVehicles2() from getVehicles. The compiler complains that there is an unhandled Exception in doing so. Wouldn't declaring the exception  with throws is not sufficient to propagate it upto the parent controller method. Try/catch would resolve the error, but I thought declaring throws would propagate relating errors to calling method.

Comment: It looks fine to me; the compiler shouldn't complain.

Comment: @mrod sorry changed the question. The call was inside a forEach loop, which is why it migth not work with throws on top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the signature of the Consumer. If you expand the lambda expression as an anonymous class, you'd get:

```
new ArrayList<>().forEach(new Consumer<Object>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(Object obj) {
        getVehicles2(req);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the *foreach* receives a *Consumer*, whose *accept* method does not have the "throws UnsupportedEncodingException" you'd need.